# UDK HUD problem

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, unreal-development-kit, unrealscript

hello
im trying to add a new element to the hud
its spoused to be a compass that should function like the minimap

Ive add this code to the main hud.swf

```
    var DcompassContainer:MovieClip = this.createEmptyMovieClip("DcompassContainer", this.getNextHighestDepth());
DcompassContainer._x = 280;
DcompassContainer._y = 8;
DcompassContainer.loadMovie("udk_compass.swf");
```

so far all is good
this is the info on the main MC in flash

name directional
instence name directional
identifier directional
class com.scaleform.directional

in the class file

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
import gfx.core.UIComponent;

class com.scaleform.directional extends UIComponent {

    // The entities, layers and controls of the minimap
    public var directionshow:MovieClip;


    public function directional() {
    //
    }   

    public function configUI():Void {   
        // Register compass values with the app
        //
        // Params: 
        //          compass movieclip (this),
        //
        ExternalInterface.call("registerDcompassView", this);
    }

}
```

in the GFxMinimapHud.uc ive added this code

```
function registerDcompassView(GFxDcompass dc)
{
    GetPC().ClientMessage("DCopmass Registered");
    Dcompass = dc;
    Dcompass.Init(self);
    Dcompass.SetVisible(false);
    Dcompass.SetFloat("_xscale", 85);
    Dcompass.SetFloat("_yscale", 85);
}
```

after adding all swf to the content browser and running the game
the swf does appear on thew screen
but the code is not working
im not getting the ClientMessage

Comment: I've just done my HUD successfully .
What's your problem exactly ? "the code(?) is not working ..."
Does your GFxDcompass class's Logic work correctly ?

Comment: check this : **http://forums.epicgames.com/threads/842146-Problem-with-GFxMinimap-%282DMapTexture%29-HUD-flaw-D**